# Join Tables on Date Range in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, left-join

I need to join tableA to tableB on employee_id and the cal_date from table A need to be between date start and date end from table B. I ran below query and received below error message, Would you please help me to correct and query. Thank you for you help!

**Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'date_start'**.

```
select a.*, b.skill_group 
from tableA a 
  left join tableB b 
    on a.employee_id= b.employee_id 
    and a.cal_date >= b.date_start 
    and a.cal_date <= b.date_end
```

Comment: use `a.cal_date between b.date_start and  b.date_end`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I gave me similar error with you syntax.  Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'date_end'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM - quoting [LanguageManual Joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)

> Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions
>   as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce
>   job.

You may try to move the BETWEEN filter to a WHERE clause, resulting in a lousy partially-cartesian-join followed by a post-processing cleanup. Yuck. Depending on the actual cardinality of your "skill group" table, it may work fast - or take whole days.

Answer (score 2):

If your situation allows, do it in two queries.

First with the full join, which can have the range; Then with an outer join, matching on all the columns, but include a where clause for where one of the fields is null.

Ex:

```
create table tableC as
select a.*, b.skill_group 
    from tableA a 
    ,    tableB b 
    where a.employee_id= b.employee_id 
      and a.cal_date >= b.date_start 
      and a.cal_date <= b.date_end;

with c as (select * from TableC)
insert into tableC
select a.*, cast(null as string) as skill_group
from tableA a 
  left join c
    on (a.employee_id= c.employee_id 
    and a.cal_date  = c.cal_date)
where c.employee_id is null ;
```

Answer (score 1):

MarkWusinich had a great solution but with one major issue. If table a has an employee ID twice within the date range table c will also have that employee_ID twice (if b was unique if not more) creating 4 records after the join. As such if A is not unique on employee_ID a group by will be necessary. Corrected below:

```
with C as
(select a.employee_id, b.skill_group 
    from tableA a 
    ,    tableB b 
    where a.employee_id= b.employee_id 
      and a.cal_date >= b.date_start 
      and a.cal_date <= b.date_end
group by a.employee_id, b.skill_group
) C
select a.*, c.skill_group
from tableA a 
left join c
  on a.employee_id = c.employee_id 
    and a.cal_date  = c.cal_date;
```

Please note: If B was somehow intentionally not distinct on (employee_id, skill_group), then my query above would also have to be modified to appropriately reflect that.