# Hive left join - conditions on where

Tags: hive, left-join

Given two tables
Table A

| idA | v1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

and
Table B

| idB | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 2 | b |
| 2 | 1 | a |

I want to get all the values from Table A, plus the information on Table B (v3) where the two ids should be the same. This is easy - left outer join!

```
select *
from A 
left join B on A.idA = B.idB
```

However, what if I need to get v1 = v2 ? I thought that I could just use `where`

```
select *
from A 
left join B on A.idA = B.idB
where B.id is null or A.v1 = B.v2
```

Unfortunately, this removes all rows from the left table (A) that did not match any on B (in this example, idA = 3). Any solution?

EDIT: as @irnerd point out, the problem as stated is very simple (just extend the on clause). The actual issue comes when v1 becomes a timestamp, that as to be between v2 and v4 (timestamps) as in

```
select *
from A 
left join B on A.idA = B.idB and a.v1 between b.v2 and b.v4
```

The previous query works fine in Oracle, but in Hive I get error...

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the join clause to qualify the second join criteria

```
select *
from A 
left join B on A.idA = B.idB
and A.v1 = B.v2
```

Comment: This is what happens when when creates an example that is a very simplified version of the problem. - in fact, v1 is a timestamp that would be between two variables from B ( and conditions in Hive inside on can't be inequalities)

Comment: Btw, even in the simplified example, why my where solution remove rows?!

Comment: In the original question - the where clause is excluding all rows that have an idB in table B - this will stamp out the join clause.  Happy to elaborate .

Comment: But why? The or condition should be meet for the rows where v1 = v2 ....

Comment: where B.id is null (or B.Bid) is null will override all other criteria - your sample data has no rows where Column B.Bid is null

Comment: thanks - I edited the question to clarify my issue. Following on your last comment, how come b.bid is null override all other criteria? Isn't this an unexpected behavior for OR clauses?

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the question - is a similar question to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944968/join-tables-on-date-range-in-hive#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=Hive%20does%20not%20support%20join,by%20a%20post%2Dprocessing%20cleanup.   -  Hive does not support joins based on ranges - only literals.  so - select *
from A 
left join B on A.idA = B.idB  where a.v1  between b.v2 and b.v4